# Why "notify()" method only wake the last thread which call "wait()"

Tags: java

I thought "notify()" should wake the first thread call "wait()". It turns out it dosen't. I am quiet confused.
I use JDK 15.0.1. Operating System is Windows 10.

```
public class Main {

public static final int t_count = 4;

public static final Main main = new Main();

public static volatile int id = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread t[] = new Thread[t_count];
    for (int i = 0; i < t_count; i++) {
        t[i] = new MyThread();
        t[i].setUncaughtExceptionHandler((t1, e) -> e.printStackTrace());
        t[i].start();
    }
    t[t_count - 1].join();
}

public static class MyThread extends Thread {
    static int integer = 0;
    static int count = 0;
    int i;

    public MyThread() {
        i = integer++;
        System.out.println(i + " initial" + " " + this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized (main) {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println(i + " is here");
                    count += 1;
                    if (count >= 40) {
                        main.notify();
                        System.out.println(i + " return");
                        return;
                    }
                    if (id == i) {
                        System.out.println(i + " do work");
                        System.out.flush();
                        id = (id + 1) % t_count;
                    }
                    System.out.println(i + " notify");
                    main.notify();
                    System.out.println(i + " wait");
                    main.wait();
                    System.out.println(i + " notified");
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It turns out two of these threads notify each other. The others are starving.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify() "The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the implementation."

Comment: That's bizarre. Why not FIFO for all cases? Has there any way to fix this behavior?

Comment: Because enforcing FIFO would make Java "tell" the operating system how to manage hardware resources. The operating system "knows" that better, so let it do its thing. There is no fix as this is not a bug nor a problem. You need to program FIFO in your code yourself or use e.g. a semaphore class that has it implemented.